# How Do You Categorize Based On Text Content?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, machine-learning, nlp

How does one automatically find categories for text based on content?

Comment: The original posting did not specify if the author already had categories, and wanted to classify, or if they did not, and needed to discover them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read **[Data Mining: Practical Machine Learning Tools and Techniques](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/book.html)** - Ian H. Witten,  Eibe Frank
2. Use **[Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/)** or **[Orange](http://www.ailab.si/orange/)**

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to look at the text classification libraries bundled with the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/).  Even if you're not familiar with Python I think you'll find the API rather intuitive.  There are many good examples in the [NLTK Book](http://www.nltk.org/book) and the people on the mailing list are quite helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to do text categorization is to use [bag-of-words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) representation. Words/ n-grams of words in each document could be used as features. With this you can represent every document as vector in metric space. Subsequently, you can apply [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) to group documents that are similar in terms of content. For instance, you may use k-means clustering with these vectors to cluster lexically similar documents together.

Python based text mining workbench, [NTLK](http://www.nltk.org/) is excellent for experimenting tasks like these quickly (in general, python is pretty good for working with text). You may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good paper written on this: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/hyukcho/classificationAlgorithm.html

Comment: The link is now dead :(

Answer (score 0):

The best way to categorize content, be it text or multimedia is to use a [taxonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_taxonomy).
Most of the well known CMSs have built in support for Taxonomy. [Drupal](http://drupal.org) has one of the best support for [taxonomy](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/taxonomy) among the various CMSs out there.

Comment: I don't think I'd call this the best way.  I'd call it *a way*.